# Docker compose to Kubernetes migration

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Actually, my organisation is using the docker compose files and they want to migrate it to Kubernetes and they had a plan to use stackpoint.io for the Kubernetes, so what is the best procedure and steps to implement Kubernetes.

Answer (score 3):

Luckily this is a rather painless process. First you'd convert your compose files to Kubernetes manifests using [kompose](http://kompose.io/) and typically would also need to manually adjust the mapping; suggest you create Helm charts here. Then, you would test them locally using [Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) and once you're satisfied, move into a prod environment. Also, think about where in your CI/CD pipeline you might need adaptations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple files you would like to convert from docker compose to Kubernetes yamls or Helm chart, you can try out move2kube (https://github.com/konveyor/move2kube).

Once you have move2kube binary in path, you will have to do,

```
move2kube translate -s <folder containing all docker compose files>
```